# How can I add a timestamp to a Tabular Editor property export? - c#

Tags: c#, powerbi

I'm using Tabular Editor connected to a PowerBI model to view the data model.  Using the Advanced Scripting option I've written a simple c# script that outputs the model's properties.  (I can then export this to excel)

```
ExportProperties(
    Model.AllMeasures.OfType<TabularNamedObject>()
    .Concat(Model.AllColumns), 
   "Parent,ObjectType,Name,Description,Expression").Output();
```

I'm looking for a way to add a timestamp into this script if that is possible.    This c# is very new to me and although I can see example online I can't see to apply it to this script successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of outputting the result of `ExportProperties` directly, you can store the string in a variable, and then manipulate that string before you output it. For example, if you want to add an additional header line with the timestamp, do something like this:

```
var tsv = ExportProperties(
    Model.AllMeasures.OfType<TabularNamedObject>().Concat(Model.AllColumns), 
    "Parent,ObjectType,Name,Description,Expression");

tsv = "Model metadata exported: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "\n\n" + tsv;

tsv.Output();
```

The result when copied into Excel:

[image]